# Midi C Library for creating a Game

Tags: c, midi

I'm creating a simple midi based game in C and I am wondering if there are any libraries to load a midi file, play and also manipulate it by getting the note values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check SDL. More especifically, [SDL_mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/).

> **Description:**
>      SDL_mixer is a sample multi-channel audio mixer library.
>   It supports any number of simultaneously playing channels of 16 bit stereo audio, plus a single channel of music, mixed by the popular MikMod MOD, Timidity MIDI, Ogg Vorbis, and SMPEG MP3 libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I've used SDL_Mixer in the past just not realised it has support for MIDI as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the MIDI and process its contents yourself rather than just playing it, `SDL_Mixer` might not be what you want. In this case I would just read the spec and write your own code. MIDI is an **extremely** simple format and you can probably write whatever code you need in 15 minutes or so... :-)

Comment: Yes - but how to generate the sound after parsing events :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question has already been answered, but I would have to agree with @R.. in that SDL is probably overkill for what you are trying to do. You should also take a look at [jdksmidi](https://github.com/jdkoftinoff/jdksmidi), a much smaller MIDI library written in C++.